# Can't install TeamViewer on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, teamviewer

I have a Dell Inspiron 6400 laptop. I was a Windows user but I want to start using Ubuntu from now on. Everything goes well except installation of the teamviewer. I have downloaded the file from the official website. There, it says that just double click on the *.deb file and it will install it automatically. Well, it gives an error:

> Failed to remove essential system package, You requested to remove a
>   package which is an essential part of your system.

Then I tried the second way of installation, which is on the terminal. I types as suggested: sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb. It started installing but later on failed. HEre is the copy of the screen.

```
Preparing to replace teamviewer7:i386 7.0.9377 (using teamviewer_linux.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement teamviewer7:i386 ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer7:i386:
 teamviewer7:i386 depends on bash (>= 3.0).
 teamviewer7:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.7).
 teamviewer7:i386 depends on libasound2.
 teamviewer7:i386 depends on zlib1g.
 teamviewer7:i386 depends on libxext6.
dpkg: error processing teamviewer7:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer7:i386
```

I have already checked these dependent files in Synaptic and they are all installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to install a 32bit copy onto a 64bit machine?

Comment: I am trying 32 bit one.

Comment: sudo `apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 2):

**Correct way to install Team viewer**

Download Team viewer according to your arc 386/amd64

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
```

You can now **double click** on team viewer that you have recently downloaded, it will open in software center and click on install

Why need to add wine ppa ?

because Team viewer completely run on wine, so some time it misses the files if you don't have wine ppa added.

Answer (score 0):

you should try it one more time then .
do this in your terminal one by one

```
sudo dpkg -r teamviewer7:i386
sudo apt-get update
```

then try again with your install .

Answer (score 0):

According to [Team Viewer's documentation](https://www.teamviewer.com/hi/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx) this are the steps needed to install it:

1. For 32-bit DEB-systems you need the teamviewer_i386.deb package. 
   For 64-bit DEB-systems without Multiarch you need the teamviewer_amd64.deb package. Please see note on Multiarch below. For installing TeamViewer, we recommend using the graphical installer.
2. If you prefer to use the command line, for the 32-bit package:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
   ```

   For the 64-bit package:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
   ```
3. In case “dpkg” indicates missing dependencies, complete the installation by executing the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```